# Asynchronous send/receive client

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I have a client that reads messages from RabbitMq and sent it to a server, the IP of the server is specified in the message, I want the sending and receiving parts to be asynchronous because I will be dealing with multiple servers and I don't want the code to hang and wait for a response. by asynchronous I mean the send and receive work in parallel. any suggestion ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSockets for this. The send and receive part are event-driven and work in parallel.

If you already have sending and receiving mechanism and you just want them to be in parallel, have a look at greenlets in python.

Comment: I was playing around with select library but after sending the message it gets stuck at the receiving part so I think I my mechanism is invalid. I will check Websockets for sure. thanks

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it ? @WaterByte

Comment: Check this code: https://github.com/humblewolf/Kaldiwolf/blob/master/ClientWolf.py . See outgoing_mic and incoming function which uses websockets. And see how greenlets parallelize them.